# How to make schtasks work after the user's password has changed?

Tags: passwords, scheduling, windows-task-scheduler

On Windows machines, [schtasks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) is a utility similar to cron for scheduling jobs to run on a regular basis.

Problem is, when you define a schtask, you must specify the userid *and* password of the account to run the job.

Then later, when the user changes his password, that schtask will no longer work. It must be deleted and rescheduled with the *new* password.

So, how can I setup a scheduled job (via schtasks, at, whatever) that's immune to password changes?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't *quite* answer your question, but a common workaround is to create a user (with appropriate privileges) and use that account solely for executing scheduled tasks.

As the user account is created with a non-expiring password, the sysadmin who creates it should choose an appropriately strong password.

Comment: Hah, just when I wanted to click "Post your answer"...beat me to it ;-) +1

Comment: In a production environment this is general the best practice as well. Regular user accounts can have their permissions changed or revoke, or can be removed or disabled entirely. A service account is much easier to manage, as well as limit the scope of.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your command:

```
/RU "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /RP *
```

Will run as System and ignore passwords.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to update existing tasks.  In cmd prompt you would use the following to help you:

```
schtasks /change /tn TaskName [/s computer [/u [domain\]user /p password]] [/tr TaskRun] [/ru [Domain\]User | "System"] [/rp Password]
```

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true